# Is it good practice to pass method in a HashSet?

Tags: java, methods, set, hashset

Is it a good practice to pass method in HashSet like below where i have passed the methods directly inside HashSet?

> Set byPrice = new HashSet(getProductsByPriceFilter(
>                     lowPrice, highPrice));**

```
  public Set<Product> filterProducts(BigDecimal lowPrice,
                BigDecimal highPrice, String manufacturer, String category) {

            Set<Product> byPrice = new HashSet<Product>(getProductsByPriceFilter(
                    lowPrice, highPrice));
            Set<Product> byManufacturer = new HashSet<Product>(
                    getProductsByManufacturer(manufacturer));
            Set<Product> byCategory = new HashSet<Product>(
                    getProductsByCategory(category));

            byPrice.retainAll(byManufacturer);
            byPrice.retainAll(byCategory);

            return byPrice;
        }
```

Comment: You aren't passing a method to the `HashSet` constructor, you're passing the return value of `getProductsByPriceFilter()`.

Comment: But is there any more efficient to accomplish this?

Comment: yes so instead I shud use loop to add all the values to set. I am sort of new to learning java.

Comment: If your code isn't running too slowly, don't worry about efficiency, worry about readability.  If you code is running too slowly, get a profiler.

Comment: Your approach is not wrong and it should not hamper the execution time as well.

Answer (score 2):

One thought on this: if your method already returns something that could fill your entire Set - why not have the method **return** that Set?

```
Set<Product> byPrice = getProductsByPriceFilter(
                lowPrice, highPrice));
```

With some

```
public Set <Product> getProductsByPriceFilter(double low, double high) {
```

Same then for the other filters.

Or... pass the already filtered set into the next stage. You probably have a loop over all products in `getProductsByManufacturer ()`. If you added the already filtered set as parameter you could reduce this loop to loop over all products that already are in price range and so on.